# unable to install pg-native (libpq-dev) on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-native on a container.

Looks like I've to install postgresql (server) to install libpq-dev. I don't want to install postgresql server on a container, as it has to only connect to server.

I tried installing on postgresql-client but no use. I'm using ubuntu:14.04 . Any suggestions?

If I'm doing something completely please wrong let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`libpq-dev` doesn't install the full server but does install a lot of development dependencies. The `pg-native` node module doesn't supply pre built binaries so you need to install all the dev dependencies for npm to complete the build for you.

If you are concerned about your image size, it is possible to build the node module in a `build` container with all the build dependencies to  create a `tar.gz` of it. Then extract the built package into your app instead of using `npm install`. This can be done generally for all node modules to speed up your build process and remove all build tools from the docker image you run the application from.